# Midi out from a keyboard to PA on a budget?

Tags: keyboard, midi

My brother has this keyboard that feels great to play, but only has one decent tone.  Its only outputs are a 1/8 inch headphone jack OR midi, which got me wondering if there were any hardware units built for midi->tone library processed out to 1/4 inch for a PA.

What are some options for adding a tone library to the output?

Are there standalone units? Is there computer software that would make switching tones easy in a live situation?

Comment: Welcome to the site! http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42394/cheap-way-to-make-sound-from-a-midi-keyboard-without-pc may be of interest regarding using standalone hardware modules. Using a PC is possible too but probably introduces more complications if you're just getting started.

Answer (score 2):

Having an actual MIDI output (instead of USB MIDI) is a good thing, because this allows you to connect devices without a PC inbetween.

Rack-mount modules (e.g., [Motif-Rack XS](http://uk.yamaha.com/en/products/music-production/tone-generators/motif-rack_xs/?mode=model), [Integra-7](http://www.rolandus.com/products/integra-7/)) are large, and correspondingly costly,
but there are also "desktop" modules, such as the [Mobile Studio Canvas](http://www.rolandus.com/products/mobile_studio_canvas/). It might be cheaper to buy some used, discontinued model (e.g., SD-20/50/80, SC-8820/8850, SC-88(Pro), MU500/1000/2000).

Using a PC/laptop is always possible (with suitable software), and switching tones through MIDI will work if your keyboard has the controls for that.
However, even with a good sound device (that has good drivers), latency can never be as low as with a hardware module (whether the difference matters for you is another question). Furthermore, a general-purpose machine always will have software/configuration problems, and might not be available when you feel like jamming.

Comment: Also, don't worry about the size of the audio connectors.  A domestic keyboard may have 1/8" jacks, more professional gear may use 1/4" jacks or XLRs.  But they'll all connect perfectly well to a mixer, with a suitable cable.