# Cheapest portable battery-operated simple MIDI-triggered drum sample-player

Tags: midi

Okay, that's a mouthful.

My questions stems from my initial quest to make a suitcase/cajon bass drum/tambourine combo that can be played with foot pedals while simultaneously playing an amplified acoustic guitar.

This is a common idea - see it well implemented here: [

Before I got too deep into designing the thing, I realised I could grab the hi-hat pedal and kick drum from my electric drum kit.

Much more compact, no need to isolate the tambourine from the bass drum, and I can program and adjust any number of sounds I want using the drum module!

The problem... when performing I would have to carry around the rather large drum module, and have access to a power source.

I'd rather have a scaleable setup - a guitar amp and drum module that can either run on mains power or battery power.

So my challenge became kind of small, just find a tiny device that can take the MIDI input from two foot pedals, and ideally be programmable with maybe 5 different percussive sounds.

Every path I've followed seems to be overkill, people suggesting MPCs and KP3s.

I want to spend < $100.

Here's a thread with some good ideas: [Cheap way to make sound from a MIDI keyboard, without PC](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42394/cheap-way-to-make-sound-from-a-midi-keyboard-without-pc)

It seems all the suggestions are how to play piano samples on a MIDI keyboard, and not drum sounds.

Surely there's a simple way to do this very cheaply?

Comment: MIDI Channel 10 usually produces drum sounds instead of notes.

Comment: @luser-droog thanks for the reply. TBH I don't know much about MIDI or synthesisers, but are you saying that the solutions in the thread I linked could work just as well for me?

Comment: Yes, I think so. For more info, see [wikipedia on the General Midi standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI#Percussion).